# Type Mismatch in code to populate a combobox

Tags: excel, vba

This code was working perfectly yesterday but now I get a type mismatch run time error 13. I have tried to research the issue but don't understand vba well enough to solve it.

All I have changed today is some sheet names which I have now undone but it still will not work.

```
Dim WKB As Workbook
Dim SHT_data_WORKERS As Worksheet
Set WKB = ActiveWorkbook
Set SHT_data_WORKERS = WKB.Sheets("data_WORKERS")
Dim vArr As Variant
Dim i As Integer
vArr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SHT_data_WORKERS.Range("B2:B" & SHT_data_WORKERS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value)
With form_addTask.form_addTask_Worker
    .Clear
    For i = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
        .AddItem vArr(i)
    Next i
End With
```

**EDIT -** 
I've narrowed the problem down to the following line;

```
vArr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SHT_data_WORKERS.Range("B2:B" & SHT_data_WORKERS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value)
```

I do not get any errors when there are two or more rows filled in on the SHT_data_WORKERS page.

So this is the structure of the SHT_data_WORKERS page where the list is pulled from during an error;

```
ID | Name | Role
1    Chris Engineer
```

However it works when there are two rows entered;

```
ID | Name | Role
1    Chris Engineer
2    Test  Engineer
```

Does anyone now how to format the code to work when there is only 1 entry?

Thanks

Comment: The range is only 3 rows at the moment, is there a limit for the transpose function? I'm not sure where the exact error occurs as the debug highlights the line that calls the form in another module `form_addTask.Show`

Comment: Ah... that is not the problem then. If you step through with F8 is that still the line which throws the error?

Comment: Maybe the problem is not the code itself but it thrown by the code of the form (eg `Init`-event?)

Comment: If i step through the error appears as it tries to do `.AddItem vArr(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have invalid values in your sheet, eg a `#N/A`. Note that this is not a string, Excel handles such error values with an own vartype.

Check if the value is okay before adding it:

```
    If Not IsError(vArr(i)) Then
        .AddItem vArr(i)
    End If
```

**Update** (after you added some more information to your question):
If your data contains only one row, the `transpose` will get only one cell as parameter (`B2:B2`). In that case, you get a single value as result, not an array.

So change your code to

```
   With form_addTask.form_addTask_Worker
        .Clear
        If IsArray(vArr) Then
            For i = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
                If Not IsError(vArr(i)) Then .AddItem vArr(i)
            Next i
        Else
            If Not IsError(vArr) Then .AddItem vArr
        End If
    End With
```

(of course it's up to you to decide if you want to keep the check for error before adding the item)

Comment: no luck - get the same error message. There are only 2 rows of data in the range and both are text values

Comment: Does the error occurs at the first first `AddItem`? What is the content of `vArr(i)` at that moment? Does something like `.AddItem i` work?

Comment: hi - the question has been updated above to narrow the problem down! Thanks